# Unable to build a program using lablgtk2 with jbuilder

Tags: ocaml, lablgtk, ocaml-dune

I would like to use `jbuilder` when compiling with `lablgtk2` but I am having problems getting these error messages:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Thread referenced from /Users/hadilsabbagh/.opam/4.05.0/lib/lablgtk2/gtkThread.cmx
         Mutex referenced from /Users/hadilsabbagh/.opam/4.05.0/lib/lablgtk2/gtkThread.cmx
         Condition referenced from /Users/hadilsabbagh/.opam/4.05.0/lib/lablgtk2/gtkThread.cmx
```

Here is my `jbuild`:

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(executable
  ((name simple)
  (libraries (lablgtk2))
  ))
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Most likely, your `jbuild` is missing a dependency on `core` (due to `gtkThread.cmx`) , it should work with the follwing jbuild file :

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(executable
  ((name simple)
  (libraries (core lablgtk2))
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [this issue](https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues/96). jbuilder/dune adds the `mt` predicate automatically, which means that if your library supplies a threaded option it will be used, and you need to add `threads` as a dependency:

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(executable
  ((name simple)
  (libraries (threads lablgtk2))
  ))
```

Note that the order of libraries is significant in ocaml, `threads` needs to come before `lablgtk2`.